# How does one extract the slide transition time from a PPTX file

Tags: xml-parsing, powerpoint

I'm trying to parse a PPTX file and get the slide durations and slide transition times.
I often come across XML like the one shown below.

How does one extract the slide transition time from this snippet?
It seems that the value of "p14:dur" would be the length of the transition.
However, I've found that this value is not accurate.
Are there any descriptions of the "spd" attribute?
I've tried searching the web, but haven't found what 'spd="slow"' might mean.

```html
<mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main">
  <mc:Choice Requires="p14">
    <p:transition spd="slow" p14:dur="2000" advTm="18026"/>
  </mc:Choice>
  <mc:Fallback xmlns="">
    <p:transition spd="slow" advTm="18026"/>
  </mc:Fallback>
</mc:AlternateContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Office Open XML](http://officeopenxml.com/prSlide-transitions.php) the advTm is the amount of time the slide is shown. dur seems to be the duration of the animation for a given slide.

Look into OOXML(Microsoft seems to be the leader here)